# Overflow exception double into int

Tags: c#

In debugging mode this line of code double divided by int result in an System.Overflow exception. The value for the int32 was too small/large.

The result of `0.0d/0 is NaN`. Which does not fit into a int obviously.

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(0.0d/0);
```

But how do I handle that scenario correctly that no exception happens? Or should I try catch it?

Comment: The real question here is: why are you dividing by zero?

Comment: All / most integer overflows are dependent on compilation options.

Comment: It should be easy to fix with a simple condition, don't divide if the value of divisor is 0.

Comment: How about: `double calculatedDoubleValue = 0.0d/0; int result; if (calculatedDoubleValue > Int32.MinValue && calculatedDoubleValue < Int32.MaxValue) { result = (int)calculatedDoubleValue; } else { /* handle case where it doesn't fit */ }`

Comment: Btw. after some quick tests, it seems that `tryCatch` is *slightly* faster, even if >50% of the conversions fail. If every conversion fails, it's only *very slightly* slower than checking the range.

Comment: @Corak You shouldnt use exceptions as part of expected workflows, even if it is faster. It makes real exception handling complicated. Having the debugger halt on all those expected exceptions is a real pain for instance

Comment: @Master_T You were right, I could check in my business layer if the variable with 0 is null then return 0 because nothing can be calculated then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that depends entirely on your applications expectations.

If you know the double can be NaN or just larger than Int32.MaxValue and you like the function to continue with a specific result, you should write a check.

If an overflow is an actual exception that needs to be handled up-stack by some special logic, you should throw an exception.

Comment: "I'd say that depends entirely on your applications expectations." correctly and therefore my business logic tested the  0 value to be 0 then return 0 for the 0.0 variable... thanks for eye opener!

Answer (score 2):

The byte size of an `int` is too small to fit all possible `double` values. See [Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Your best option is to carry out the conversion in a try-block and catch the `OverflowException`.

```
try
{
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(0.0d/0);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    //...          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know what this calculation is supposed to calculate, so you should be already able to decide if 'NaN' is OK and what should be put into that `int` when such result occurs. You may catch it. You may add `if`s to make sure it doesnt happen. You may leave it. You may do whatever you need, but first, you need to decide **what** you want to occur when a `0.0` happens. It is there for some reason.

Seeing `0.0/0.0` usually mean an error **earlier** in the code. 0/0 almost never makes sense, hence Not-a-Number is the result to remind about it.

In general, you may want to trace and diagnose why the division-by-zero occurred. Check why the second variable is zero (why was that /0.0 and not i.e. /1.0 ?), decide if it is a valid possible value and if it is not OK then fix the code responsible for that zero, so zero won't occur at all.

For instance, if you had a formula `forcepower(x,z) / distance(x,z)` and both the power and the distance turned out to be zeros because `x` and `z` were the same point, then you may add an `if` checking x==z and force the result to be 0.0 in such case. But, if that formula calculated foobarized whachamacallit then you should pick the most frublastic number. I don't know. You should.

---edit

Ok, after your comments I understand it now. So you've got control over all values that are used in division - good!

Since you already test 'bar' for zero and in this case force 'foo' to zero (I've seen your comment about 'because nothing can be calculated then') then the problem is in fact in the way you have designed, or, 'encoded' the results.

Forcing something to `0.0` or `0` isn't a really good way of indicating that "nothing was calculated". In later parts of the code you will have a hard time telling if the `bazz` is `0` because it was the result, or because it was not calculated.

Sure, of course, if `0` is an actually invalid value that normally can never occur, then its *sometimes* ok to use it as a special "nothing"-indicating value..

..but as you saw from that 0/0 case, it can cause inobvious problems, and also it will force you **to remember to check** in every place if 'values are good':

```
double foo;
if(bar != 0) foo = calculate_the_foo(); // check the Bar maybe it's zero
else foo = 0.0;   // can't calculate, no foo

double z;
if(bar != 0) z = foo/bar;  // added a check against zero in bar again..
else z = ...um? what to use here.. 0 again?

int result = Convert.ToInt32(z);

// later in the code
if(result != 0)  //..again? but.. is it result of 0 or no result?
   ..

// and so on
```

It is **very easy** to forget to check for special values and to simply write `result = foo/bar` and get Infinites, NaNs or Overflows.

Therefore, it is **much better** to use a 0 to really mean normal zero and to use a proper no-value thing for indicating a missing data..

..and the simplest one is plain old ... `null`.

If you use nullables like `int?` or `double?`, then you can simply write things like:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double? foo = 5.0;
        double? bar = 4.0;
        double? result = foo/bar;
        Console.WriteLine("x/y: " + prettynulls(result));
        // ^writes: 1.25

        foo = null;
        bar = 4.0;
        result = foo/bar;
        Console.WriteLine("null/y: " + prettynulls(result));
        // ^writes: (null)

        foo = 5.0;
        bar = null;
        result = foo/bar;
        Console.WriteLine("x/null: " + prettynulls(result));
        // ^writes: (null)

        foo = null;
        bar = null;
        result = foo/bar;
        Console.WriteLine("null/null: " + prettynulls(result));
        // ^writes: (null)
    }

    private static string prettynulls(double? val)
    {
        return val == null ? "(null)" : val.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please observe that you can even do operations like +-/* on them without tons of `if`s to check for nulls. Mathematic operations simply will return null if one operand was null. Hence your case would become:

```
double? foo;
if( ... ) foo = calculate_the_foo();
else  foo = null;

int? result = (int?)( foo/bar );
```

of by making the `calculate` smart with nullables when foo can't be calculated:

```
double? foo = calculate_the_foo();

int? result = (int?)( foo/bar );
```

Look at the simplicity and expressiveness. Nullables like `double?` even handle casting. A `double?` that holds a `null`, when casted to `int?` will simply be return `null`. Otherwise it will cast the double value to int and return int.

Comment: it is 0.0/0      .    .      .

Comment: @Elisabeth: not a `foo/bar` variables which happen to be zero for some reason? you mean, it is literally hardcoded as `0.0/0`? that's a complete nonsense. check who wrote that code and ask them why did they did that. Maybe they left it there to always throw as a "to-do".

Comment: Nono sorry for misunderstanding. of course its foo/bar but the data in their might be 0.0 (foo) and 0 (bar. but if bar is 0 then foo must be 0 too so I check if bar is 0 then I return 0 for foo :-)

Comment: @Elisabeth: Ok, I understand. I started to write a reply in comments and it greeeeeew looong, so I added the response to my answer. Please see the `edit` part. I think you can make a good use of that hints to make your code simpler.

Comment: "...if the bazz is 0 because it was the result, or because it was not calculated." I don`t care for that I just return 0 to the UserInterface. The user does not care :-)